# to merge two dictionaries in python with common keys and min values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two dictionaries

```
dict1[1]={ 'a':3 , 'b':2 , 'c':1 , 'd':5 }
dict1[2]={ 'a':2 , 'd':2 ,'e':2 }
```

Now i want to merge them with common keys and minimum value of the common keys, as after merging dict1[1] and dict1[2]

```
aftermerging={'a':2 , 'd':2}
```

Suggest me an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension* that takes items from one dictionary if the keys exist in the other, and then apply `min` to the values of both:

```
d = { 'a':3 , 'b':2 , 'c':1 , 'd':5 }
c = { 'a':2 , 'd':2 ,'e':2 }
r = {k: min(v, d[k]) for k,v in c.items() if k in d}
print(r)
# {'a': 2, 'd': 2}
```

Comment: Op precised he was looking for the `min()`.

Comment: `for k,v in c.items()` I guess, because there is too many values to unpack otherwise. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using dict comprehension and set operations:

```
{k:min(dict1[k],dict2[k]) for k in dict1.viewkeys() & dict2}
```

Comment: @JonClements oooh, I learned something new, thanks! Answer updated.

Comment: pytonic level: legendary!

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {}
dict1[1]={ 'a':3 , 'b':2 , 'c':1 , 'd':5 }
dict1[2]={ 'a':2 , 'd':2 ,'e':2 }

aftermerging = { x:min(dict1[1][x],dict1[2][x]) for x in set(dict1[1]) & set(dict1[2]) }

print aftermerging 

>> {'a':2 , 'd':2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your question **To merge two dictionaries in python with common keys and min values.**

I am going to split this problem into two parts.

1) Find the common keys.

2) Use those common keys to find the common key min value.

**Find the common keys**

```
In [1]: dict1 = { 'a':3 , 'b':2 , 'c':1 , 'd':5 }

In [2]: dict2 = { 'a':2 , 'd':2 ,'e':2 }
In [3]: common_keys = [key for key in dict1.keys() if key in dict2.keys()]

In [4]: common_keys
Out[4]: ['a', 'd']
```

**Use those common keys to find the common key min value.**

```
In [5]: aftermerging = {}

In [6]: for i in range(0,len(common_keys)):
            aftermerging[common_keys[i]] = min(dict1[common_keys[i]],dict2[common_keys[i]])

In [7]: aftermerging
Out[7]: {'a': 2, 'd': 2}
```